# Understanding TensorboardX graph

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard, tensorboardx

I'm inspecting my model in the tensorboardX. I'm using PyTorch. Following is the `forward` method:

```py
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.net(x)
        x = x.view(x.shape[0], -1)  # flat
        x = self.ext_net(x)
        x = F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)

        return x
```

In the graph, I don't understand what these values and nodes in blue and green boxes represent. Why is there a separate dataflow from `input` to `ext_net` (*FCNCustom*)? Shouldn't there be only one coming through `net`?

[image]